# ghci loads slowly for the first time

Tags: ghci

OS: Linux Slackware 14.2. ghci 8.4.3.

It takes around 10 seconds to start ghci for the first time. After that it starts quickly. I thought that it tries to load some libraries.

```
$ strace ghci
```

gives an interesting output:

```
open("/usr/lib/ghc-8.4.3/bin/../haskeline-0.7.4.2/libffi.so.7", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ghc-8.4.3/bin/../stm-2.4.5.0/libffi.so.7", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ghc-8.4.3/bin/../ghc-8.4.3/libffi.so.7", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ghc-8.4.3/bin/../terminfo-0.4.1.1/libffi.so.7", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ghc-8.4.3/bin/../ghci-8.4.3/libffi.so.7", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ghc-8.4.3/bin/../ghc-boot-8.4.3/libffi.so.7", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ghc-8.4.3/bin/../transformers-0.5.5.0/libffi.so.7", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ghc-8.4.3/bin/../hpc-0.6.0.3/libffi.so.7", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ghc-8.4.3/bin/../template-haskell-2.13.0.0/libffi.so.7", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

There is more like this. The same happens for the libraries:

- libncursesw.so.5
- librt.so.1
- libutil.so.1
- libdl.so.2
- libpthread.so.0
- libgmp.so.10
- libc.so.6

Despite the fact that all these libraries are located in either `/lib` or `/usr/lib` it tries to find them inside internal ghc directories. What's going on? Can I fix it?

Comment: When you say `for the first time` do you mean the first time each boot? Also, do you see any noticeable differences in the `strace` output between the fast and slow runs?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yes, every time I reboot it takes long time to launch ghci for the first time. After that ghci loads quickly.